# kafka consumer in R

Tags: python, r, apache-kafka

I am looking to hack together a kafka consumer in Python or R (preferably R).
Using the kafka console consumer I can grep for a string and retrieve the relevant data but I am at a loss when it comes to parsing it suitably in R.

There are kafka clients available in other languages (for example: PHP, CPP) but one in R would be helpful from a data analytics point of view.

It would be great if the expert R developers on this forum could hint at/suggest resources that would allow me to make headway in this direction.

Apache Kafka : incubator.apache.org/kafka/

Kafka Consumer Client(s) : https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/clients

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is a [C++ API for Kafka](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/clients/cpp), you could use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) to bring it to R.

*Edit* in response to comment on R-only solution: I do not know Kafka well enough to answer, but generally speaking, middleware runs fast, connecting multiple clients, streams etc.  So you would to simplify some thing somewhere to get R (single-threaded as it is) to play with it.

Comment: Is it possible to have a pure R solution in your opinion ?

Comment: I expanded my answer--and I suspect not.

Comment: I'm from the future - it looks like the supported C++ api these days is https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka .

Answer (score 5):

[2015 Update] there is a library that allows you to connect to kafka - **`rkafka`**

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rkafka/rkafka.pdf

Comment: Any opinion on using rkafka? How stable it is?

Comment: I'm using `rkafka` now, but it is not being maintained, the author is unresponsive, and the package is not well suited for automation (e.g., errors are printed directly to the R console, not thrown as an "exception" and cannot be captured). Any updates or info on other implementations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Until someone will start porting cpp client, nothing will change. Fortunately there are a lot of header only cpp clients. It should be fairly straightforward to work with them... And thanks for sharing your experience with `rkafka`!

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov unfortunately, the only one I found ([libkafka-asio](https://github.com/danieljoos/libkafka-asio)) requires "boost-thread" which, unless I'm mistaken, [isn't supported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19658449/3358272), at least under windows (and not included in [`RcppBoost`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/bh/) as of 1.60.0-2). Is there another header library that isn't based on Boost?

Comment: seems the most straight way is to try to develop r bindings to librdkafka... At least all kafka version will be supported. But yes, it is not header only.

Comment: @r2evans recently I implemented another simple jvm-based client - https://github.com/dselivanov/rscalaKafka.