# Is it possible to build an R package, which use Rcpp and Boost.Thread, on [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, r, boost, rcpp

Recently, I have made an R package, which use Rcpp to integrate R and C++.  And the C++ library Boost is used for multithreading.  I wonder if is it possible for my package to be built on http://win-builder.r-project.org/?

I found that a Make variable --- BOOSTLIB --- is defined, as shown in http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ThirdPartySoftware.html.

I tried to use the header-only libraries, it's OK, but when I tried to use separately-compiled library Boost.Thread, either "no such file" or "undefined reference" error came out.  Maybe the lib path was wrong.  However, I can hardly find any words explained on win-builder.  Can I only use the header-only libraries or Is there a way to configure Makevars.win to find the separately-compiled Boost.Thread library?

Or maybe I can include Boost source filed in my package, but I don't think it is a good way, and I also don't know how to include (I haven't tried).

I found there is an R package BH trying to provide Boost for R.  It is very helpful, and I appreciate the work done by the authors of BH very much, however, the Boost.Thread is not included when I asked this question.  Maybe I can wait until when they include Boost.Thread.  But I prefer to do it myself now, so I can learn more.

Comment: Not likely that Boost.Thread, will be included in BH. BH is for header only libraries.

Comment: Headers are not 'libraries' per say. They are bits of code that you include in to your own code. Boost thread on the other hand is a binary library, or compiled piece of code. To use it, you need to not only include the relevant boost/thread header files but also link against the actual library file. If you don't link against it, you'll end up with undefined references.

Comment: @BenJ: Thank you, but are there any variables I can use to indicate in Makevars.win for the Boost.Thread binary on [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org)?

Comment: I've no experience with win-builder but judging by the second link you've posted, and as you've no doubt guessed, you probably need to set BOOSTLIB to the path of the boost library files (normally to be found in path/where/boost/is/installed/lib/). I would suggest that as a start you install the latest version of boost.

Comment: @BenJ: Thank you.  You are right.  However, win-builder is a website that provides service for building R packages, so it is not possible for me to set BOOSTLIB.  I am an R newbie, using win-builder is the only way I know to build a compatible or portable R package under Windows.  And I have tried to use ${BOOSTLIB}/lib in the Make variable PKG_LIBS of Makevars.win.  But from the results of 00install.out, I think that the directory ${BOOSTLIB}/lib doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current [BH](http://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) maintainer here. Several points:

- As noted, our [BH](http://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) package only provides (a subset of) headers from Boost. The package grows as needed, we may add more soon (as I have one request in).
- Win-Builder supports `BOOSTLIB` to also set headers on Windows; as the comments say I do not think it provides libraries. In [RQuantLib](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib) I only use it to get headers as well which are needed by the QuantLib classes.
- Several package have fought the threading issue on Windows; the fellow BH-coauthors Jay and Mike tried in the context of their [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package and its support packages such as 
  [synchronicity](http://cran.r-project.org/package=synchronicity).  But as of now, they are not provided Windows support because, well, Windows is different and at pains with some Unix idioms.

*Edit:* Here is the [README](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/synchronicity/README) from [synchronicity](http://cran.r-project.org/package=synchronicity):

> synchronicity is currently only supported on unix platforms  because
>   of a bug in either Boost or MinGW with 64-bit Windows.  We'll expand
>   support to Windows as soon as these have been  resolved.
>
> If you want to use this package with 32-bit Windows, it may be 
>   possible (comment out the OS_type line in DESCRIPTION).
>
> October 30, 2010.  Modified configure to fix up a Solaris problem.

No in short there is *no* pre-built tool for you to rely on.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's very helpful.  I noticed that [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) and [synchronicity](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/synchronicity/index.html) have a field OS_type to indicate their use on Unix.  In other words, I only need to provide Unix version of an R package if I want to upload my package on CRAN?

Comment: I know about [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) provided by R core team.  If I use Rtools to compile Boost.Thread and related other Boost source files (though I don't know how), and then pack the generated binary files together with my C++ source files and corresponding configuration in Makevars.win to [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/), will it be possible? Or is that forbidden by R rules?

Comment: @Simon: Q1: Yes. See what synchronicity, and hence bigmemory do. There are more Unix-only or Windows-only packages. The `OS_type` is documented in the WRE manual.  Q2: I suppose but r-devel may be a better place to discuss than this comment box.  Lastly, if you found this useful the custom is to upvote and/or accept  (click on up-arrow and tickmark, respectively).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will be glad to see you at r-devel to discuss with you.  And I find that upvote requires 15 reputations.

Comment: Almost here: now you have rep 15 :)   See you over on r-devel, and for Rcpp (and possibly Rcpp + Boost) on rcpp-devel.